# Lightning-combobox getting cut off

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I am building a lightning web component that uses a combobox. It seems to be having its dropdown portion cut short by the bounds of its container.

I've tried adding height, z-index, overflow, and margin modifiers to the style sheet for the input element and its container, and the only thing that's had a visible effect is adding margin to the combobox's container, which just makes more space for the dropdown to show its contents but doesn't solve the problem.

Here is an excerpt of the html file:

```
    <div class="slds-col slds-grid">
        <!-- Complete Task -->
        <div class="slds-grid slds-col slds-size_2-of-4 slds-p-right_small slds-truncate">
          <div class="slds-col">
            <div class="slds-border_bottom" style="background-color: #ecd4b566">Log a Call</div>
            <div class="slds-grid_vertical slds-p-top_small">
              <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-combobox 
                  class="spencer_combobox"
                  variant="label-hidden" 
                  placeholder="-- Call Result --" 
                  options={callResults} 
                  value={selectedResult}
                  required
                  onchange={handleResultSelection}>
                </lightning-combobox>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-textarea maxlength=255 placeholder="Write comments here" onchange={handleComment} value={commentValue}></lightning-textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-button class="slds-col" variant="Brand" label="Complete Task" onclick={handleCompleteTaskClick} disabled={buttonDisabled}></lightning-button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I expected the dropdown to be visible on top of the other elements, but it ends up hidden or cut off.

[Here is a screenshot; the dropdown menu isn't being cut off by the next element below it, it's actually getting cut off by its own bounds.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjupW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
I put `slds-truncate` in the class of the container, and that comes with `overflow:hidden`, so I was able to just remove the truncate or edit the style sheet to fix the problem.